# PhoneGap allow save image from external URL

Tags: image, cordova, webview, save

how i can allow user save images by long pressing on image on PhoneGap Webview? Now if i pressing on image nothing happened, but in native browser pop up menu with (Save image as, Save image, Set as wallpaper). I need this happen in PhoneGap like in native webrowser.

```
package com.phonegap.helloworld;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;
import android.view.WindowManager;


public class App extends DroidGap {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
        super.setStringProperty("loadingDialog", "Loading please wait...");

        super.loadUrl("http://www.mywebsite.com", 5000);


    }
}
```